# Loop object properties vs numerically indexed array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, loops, dictionary

Which is faster in JavaScript: looping through an array with integer indices or looping through an object with properties? What is the performance difference, if any?

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
}
```

Compared to:

```
var object = {"1":1, "2":2, "3":3};
for (var x in object) {
}
```

To the best of my understanding JavaScript arrays are actually backed by a map, so I would expect both to perform the same. Any information is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I should probably clarify that I'm interested in the loop overhead (like if `for in` is more expensive) and also the lookup time of accessing each element (`object[x]` vs `array[i]`).

Comment: jsperf.com is right there for you to use...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer uses an invalid benchmark and is completely wrong. As the comments point out `console.log` will dominate the test results, rendering them useless. Take a look at this comparison: http://jsperf.com/performance-of-array-vs-object/17

Array iteration is about 48 times faster than object iteration. It improves considerably if you know the range of the keys of the object in advance, but is still significantly slower than array iteration.

Answer (score 0):

i created a jsperf http://jsperf.com/array-vs-object-loop.

i thought the extra property-access would need more time. in chrome 24 it doesnt make much of a difference, in firefox 19 the object way needs 5-10% longer.

you should probably also take the size of the object/array into account.

EDIT: forget about that answer, an take a look at the accepted one!

Comment: thanks! i didnt know about this site for creating performance tests.

Comment: Seems like you're logging the entire array in the loop, instead of a single entry. This is different from the looping over the object.

Comment: yeah, youre right i my fault. i fixed it! the results seem to stay the same... (at least for me)

Comment: `console.log` is the most time consuming on that test. With no `console.log`, you can see that iterating an array is way faster than an object: http://jsperf.com/array-vs-object-loop/23